# Use a reserved word as a column name in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have to use the reserved word 'NAME' as a column name, but the vba doesn't work when I use 'NAME' as a column name. I tried to google to see if  there is anyway but I cannot find out any answer.

This is a requirement because it is a program to handle a client's data and they already use "name" as a column name. I need to import their data to my program, do some process then export it to somewhere else.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in square brackets - `[NAME]`?

Comment: I can't imagine how and why a business requirement could impose a field name to a dev. This make no sense. Don't use reserved words POINT.

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty rare that you would actually HAVE to use a reserved word as a column name, but when you do, just use square brackets `[NAME]` around the column name.

Comment: Your way is not working in access, cannot even save with [] in the name, just warning that is possible.